# How to export TFS Shelveset comments to text or excel

Tags: excel, tfs, shelveset

Can we export code review comments in a TFS Shelveset to an excel or any Text file.
I have attached this image. The comment in Red circle needs to be exported to excel or any Text file.

[image]
**Reason**- For audit purpose, need to track review comments being given to developer. Right now we have to manually enter these comments inside an excel code review sheet.

Please advise.

Comment: There is no built-in functionality, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a PowerShell script that queries the REST API see  to get a particular shelveset, I would do a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/shelvesets/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) first then a [Get Shelveset change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/shelvesets/get%20shelveset%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#itemcontent) and try and get the full changes including the comments then you can save that to a txt file for you auditors.  I haven't tried it so I don't know if comments are returned but I think so.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in or documentary way to get the comments on the Shelvesets tab, but if you try to capture the network log, you would see you can get the comments using the following API:

```
Get http://TFS2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/discussion/threads?artifactUri=vstfs%3A%2F%2F%2FVersionControl%2FShelveset%2F{CodeReviewName}%252526shelvesetOwner%25253D{ownername}
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?